# save array of objects to the mongo database using node, express

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to pre-load array of objects to MongoDB as below:

the below code works if I do one object at a time. that is,

if I set:

```
tmp_obj = { 
  id:1, 
  name: 'Tmp 1' 
}
```

## model file

```
var mongoose     = require('mongoose');
var Schema       = mongoose.Schema;

var TmpSchema   = new Schema({
    id: Number,
    name: String
});


var Tmp= mongoose.model('Tmp', TmpSchema);
module.exports = Tmp;
```

## routes file

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Tmp = require('../models/tmp');


var tmp_obj = [
  { 
    id:1, 
    name: 'Tmp 1' 
  },
  { 
    id:2, 
    name: 'Tmp 2' 
  },
  { 
    id:3, 
    name: 'Tmp 3' 
  }
];

var tmp = new Tmp(tmp_obj);

tmp.save(function (err) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);

  console.log('tmp saved to the database');
  return res.redirect('/login');
})
```

how do I push an array of objects to the mongo? and also I have multiple collections to add. so, do I do something like:

```
tmp1.save(function (err) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);

  console.log('tmp1 saved to the database');

  tmp2.save(function (err) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);

    console.log('tmp2 saved to the database');
    return res.redirect('/login');
  })
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another alternative is to use [.create()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#create_create) method, it could accept an array of objects or a single object, and you don't need to create a model instance (i.e `var tmp = new Tmp(tmp_obj);`), here is an example:

```
var Tmp = require('../models/tmp');

var tmp_obj = [
    { id:1, name: 'Tmp 1' },
    { id:2, name: 'Tmp 2' },
    { id:3, name: 'Tmp 3' }
];

Tmp.create(tmp_obj, function (err, temps) {

    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        // terminate request/response cycle
        return res.send('Error saving');
    }

    res.redirect('/login');

});
```

One last thing, don't forget to terminate the request/response cycle if an error has been occurred, otherwise the page will hangs

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method [insertMany](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#insertmany_insertMany) from mongoose to insert multiple document at once.

From the documentation of mongoose v5.0.4

```
var arr = [{ name: 'Star Wars' }, { name: 'The Empire Strikes Back' }];

Movies.insertMany(arr, function(error, docs) {});
```

---

An alternative using `.save()` would be

```
// Create all objects
const objects = tmp_obj.map(x => new Tmp(x));

try {
   // Saves objects
   const docs = await Promise.all(objects.map(x => x.save()));
} catch(e) {
  // An error happened
}
```

But **you should not use it** since `insertMany` is way better